# How to grab all values in a hash without specifying individual values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, hashmap

This is a add on for a question I asked yesterday but felt it warranted a new question.

I am taking a JSON response and want to extract all the values per iteration and put them into an array

```
@response =  { "0"=>{"forename_1"=>"John", "surname_1"=>"Smith", forename_2"=>"Josephine", "surname_2"=>"Bradley", "middle_1"=>""}, 
               "1"=>{"forename_1"=>"Chris", "surname_1"=>"Jenkins", forename_2"=>"Christine", "surname_2"=>"Sugar", "middle_1"=>""}, 
               "2"=>{"forename_1"=>"Billy", "surname_1"=>"Bob", forename_2"=>"Brenda", "surname_2"=>"Goodyear", "middle_1"=>""},
               "Status" => 100
             }
```

At present this method takes specific values that I want and puts them into the array I want.

```
col = @response.values.grep(Hash).map { |h| "#{h['forename_1']} #{h['surname_1']} #{h['forename_2']} #{h['surname_2']} #{h['middle_1']}" }
```

Is there a way however to say grab ALL the values and place them into an array (I have a response where over 25 key/value pairs are returned).

At the moment if `middle_1` has no value then a `" "` gets put into the array, ideally I would like to remove these.

Ideally I would like my newly formed array to look like

```
["John Smith Josephine Bradley", "Chris Jenkins Christine Sugar", "Billy Bob Brenda Goodyear"]
```

Even though no `middle_1` is supplied there is are no double spaces in the array. I would like to learn how to tackle this.

Comment: Can you provide example of the input JSON and clarify what output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe will provide example of "cracking" the `hash` and extracting what you would need:

```
h = {a1: "a", b2: "b", c3: "", d4: nil, e5: "e"}

values = h.values.map(&:to_s).reject(&:empty?)
# => ["a", "b", "e"]

values.join(" ")
# => "a b e"
```

Let's consider the `h.values.map(&:to_s).reject(&:empty?)`:

```
values = h.values
# => ["a", "b", "", nil, "e"]

values = values.map(&:to_s)
# => ["a", "b", "", "" "e"]

values = values.reject(&:empty?)
# => ["a", "b", "e"]
```

Hope that gives you some idea how you can proceed.

Good luck!

**UPDATE**

For provided `hash` you can quite easily reuse what I have described above like:

```
col = @response.values
               .grep(Hash)
               .map { |h| h.values.map(&:to_s).reject(&:empty?).join(" ") }

p col
# => ["John Smith Josephine Bradley", "Chris Jenkins Christine Sugar", "Billy Bob Brenda Goodyear"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Pawel i have updated my question with my scenario, I have multiple hashes in an array

Comment: Hey @Richlewis, I've updated the answer to present where would my code fit into. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes thats a great help, thank you for taking the time to put the examples together

Comment: The method you should use is `empty?` (with question mark), not `empty`

Comment: yes just realised that, that's why i removed the comment, thanks again :)

Comment: apologies to ask, but why would i get `undefined method `empty?' for 41:Fixnum (NoMethodError)`. is there anything i need to do to allow for numbers in my hash?

Comment: It's because there is no `empty?` method for `Fixnum`. In the answer I've used the one that is implemented for [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-empty-3F). Check my answer - I've updated it to handle the case you've mentioned!

Comment: Thanks again, Ill make a note to remember this